# FileReader#mark() is throwing java.io.IOException

Tags: java

This is a part of my java code, this code is throwing (java.io.IOException) at (A.java:8) please help.

```
import java.io.FileReader;


public class A {

    public A() throws Exception {
        FileReader r = new FileReader("a.txt");
        r.mark(0);

        for(int i=0; i<27; i++)
            System.out.println((char)r.read());

        r.reset();

        for(int i=0; i<27; i++)
            System.out.println((char)r.read());

        r.close();
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to enclose the `mark` in a try/catch and you should printout the exception message to help us. This is what the JavaDoc says about `mark` on Exception: " If the stream does not support mark(), or if some other I/O error occurs". So we need more info.

Comment: at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:347)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(FilterInputStream.java:226)
 at A.<init>(A.java:15)
 at A.main(A.java:24)

Answer (score 2):

`FileReader` do not support the `mark()` function

Here the related part of the code from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/Reader.java#Reader.mark%28int%29):

```
public void mark(int readAheadLimit) throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("mark() not supported");
}
```

Comment: you can use the `RandomAccessFile`, or use two Filereader or read the file in a string ind use the string for second loop.

Comment: I want to understand how the mark(); and reset(); methods are used please tell

Comment: The `java.io.StringReader` implements `mark` and `reset` so you can use this.

Comment: But java.io.StringReader reads a string I want to a read file.

Comment: Use the `java.io.BufferedReader`  This implements both function. [Here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/slides/intljava/2001ny/javaio/57.html) you have an example.

Answer (score 2):

[FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) does not support the mark operation.

You can determine this by reading the JavaDoc linked and seeing it doesn't override it or `markSupported()` inherited from [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html):

```
public boolean markSupported()

Tells whether this stream supports the mark() operation. 
The default implementation always returns false. 
Subclasses should override this method.
```